# NSObject and NSMutableArray issue

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsobject

Hello I have this NS Object:

```
@interface Checkin : NSObject {

    NSString *name;
    NSString *profID;
    NSString *time;
    NSString *lon;
    NSString *lat;
    NSString *country;
    NSString *city;
    NSString *place;
    NSString *photoURL;
    NSMutableArray *taggedID;
    NSMutableArray *taggedName;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *profID;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *time;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *lon;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *lat;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *country;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *city;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *place;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *photoURL;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *taggedID;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *taggedName;

@end
```

Now I want to create an NSMutable Array and add several "Checkins" inside of it.

When I am doing this:

```
 Checkin *checkinsA = [[NSObject alloc] init]; 

 NSDictionary *decodedJson = result;   
 NSArray *users = [decodedJson objectForKey:@"data"];

for(NSDictionary *user in users) {
    NSLog(@"Created item: %@ \n", [user objectForKey:@"created_time"]);
     checkinsA.time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[user objectForKey:@"created_time"]];
    NSDictionary *fromData = [user objectForKey:@"from"];
     NSLog(@"user id is: %@ \n", [fromData objectForKey:@"id"]);
      checkinsA.profID = [fromData objectForKey:@"id"];

     NSLog(@"user name is: %@\n ", [fromData objectForKey:@"name"]);
      checkinsA.name =[fromData objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSDictionary *placeData = [user objectForKey:@"place"];
    NSDictionary *locationData = [placeData objectForKey:@"location"];
     NSLog(@"City: %@ \n", [locationData objectForKey:@"city"]);
      checkinsA.city = [locationData objectForKey:@"city"];

     NSLog(@"Country: %@ \n", [locationData objectForKey:@"country"]);
      checkinsA.country = [locationData objectForKey:@"country"];

     NSLog(@"Latitude: %@ \n", [locationData objectForKey:@"latitude"]);
     checkinsA.lat = [locationData objectForKey:@"latitude"];

     NSLog(@"Longitude: %@ \n", [locationData objectForKey:@"longitude"]);
     checkinsA.lon = [locationData objectForKey:@"longitude"];

     NSLog(@"Place name: %@ \n", [placeData objectForKey:@"name"]);
     checkinsA.place = [placeData objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSDictionary *tagData = [user objectForKey:@"tags"];
    NSArray *tagDataArray = [tagData objectForKey:@"data"];
    for(NSDictionary *tagData2 in tagDataArray){
      NSLog(@"tagged user id is: %@ \n", [tagData2 objectForKey:@"id"]);
        [checkinsA.taggedID addObject:[tagData2 objectForKey:@"id"]];
      NSLog(@"tagged user name is: %@\n ", [tagData2 objectForKey:@"name"]);
         [checkinsA.taggedName addObject:[tagData2 objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }

    [checkinArray addObject:checkinsA];
}
```

I am getting error:

> -[NSObject setTime:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance for
>   checkinsA.time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[user objectForKey:@"created_time"]];

What is the right way to change value of the checkinsA.time checkins.id etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting that error because `checkinsA` isn't a `Checkin` object, its an `NSObject` (since that's what you alloced) and `NSObject` doesn't have a `setTime` method.  Try this instead:

```
Checkin *checkinsA = [[Checkin alloc] init];
```

Comment: OMG I feel so stupid!! Thank you very much. any suggestion how to retrieve data from checkinArray?

Comment: Assuming it's an NSMutableArray like you mention (I didn't see the declaration in the code you pasted), you can use the regular NSArray methods (like objectAtIndex:) described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

Comment: Yeah I know the objectAtIndex but I don't know the length of the array.Should I use the "count" and then objectAtIndex:i<=count?

Comment: Yes, if you want to iterate the array, you can either use a for loop bounded by checkinArray.count or enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: